# React Native not responding when I change data at Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm insert data with another way and listen on Mobile.

I can't get answers on the internet.
this is my scripts:

My rules on firebase database

```
{"rules": {".read": true,".write": true}}


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView,
  FlatList
} from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
const config = {
  //MY CONFIG
}

const app = firebase.initializeApp(config)

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.database = app.database().ref('users')//.child('users')
    this.state = {
      lists: []
    }

  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // Firebase Listener
    console.log('BEGIN');
    this.database.on('value', (data) => {
      // data.forEach( shot => {
        console.log('IN HERE', data.val());
        this.state.lists.push({...data.val()})
      // })
      // this.setState({ lists, tasksLoading: false });
    })
  }
  render() {
    const { lists, tasksLoading } = this.state;
    let taskList = ''
    if (lists.length) {
      taskList = <FlatList data={lists} renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.nama}</Text>} />;
    } else {
      taskList = <Text>Load</Text>
    }
    return (
      <View style={{margin: 4}}>
         {taskList}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Help me to fix this, thanks